# How to count and sum the values of unique occurences in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I've been struggling on something that looked simple at first, but that I can actually not solve on my own.

I have a list of items (column A), and each item has a quantity (column B). It is possible to find the same item multiple times in the list, with a different quantity. I would like to create, from that list, a list that references the unique occurrences with their total quantity throughout the whole initial list. I took a screenshot of the expected result, you can see it below (I cannot embed images yet, so I used an imgur link instead) :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbDfu.png)

I've tried the UNIQUE & SORT combination which indeed gives me the sorted list of unique occurrences, however I didn't manage to add up their values. I feel like I'm going the wrong way here.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem can be solved easily by magic `sumifs` function, you can even have multiple criteria if you need:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's actually working great, however my raw list has more than a thousand items and its size can vary. Is there a way to process this as with an ARRAYFORMULA so I can just type it once ? 

I tried this : =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2:D)) but it still doesn't expand. I might be wrong somewhere..

Comment: Little update here : playing around with formulas, I found out that "SUMIF" was actually expanding with the ARRAYFORMULA : =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(A:A,D2:D,B:B)) As I only have one criteria at the moment, I guess that would work. Is there any solution which would be more "elegant" in your opinion? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I always use `sumifs` as long as I can obtain the answer I need, I think the `arrayformula` already provide a very simple and neat formula for your to checking and updating in future when need, isn't, or you prefer super long formula to obtain the same result?

Comment: No, what you provided is actually perfect and more than enough for my question.. I'll set this as resolved, thank you!

Comment: Welcome, glad you find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY({A3:B}; "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")
```